# Writing a java script to query database via virtual machine

Tags: java, database, network-programming, database-connection, virtual-machine

So i have some small coding experience with with various languages (front to back) but nothing more than beginner level

At work, I was given a side project to do in my spare time to build my experience but for the life of me i dont know where to start

Context: company has a virtual machine we remote into which we can then use to access a database server. We can only access the database through a VM. On our local machine we can also access a webpage which displays some data from the database (we type in the IP of the VM, and we log in to the page as if we were logging into the vm)

My project was to write a script to run on our local machine that can effectively access this vm and query the database. The data i want to retrieve is also displayed on the UI

Im familiar with webscraping (where i can just get the data from the UI's DOM, but the webpage is a silverlight app and i shouldnt install anything to account for silverlight). My boss gave me hints but i'm not really understanding it

I'm somewhat paraphrasing since i dont understand:

My java script should involve using a "web service" to make an "anonymous" connection to the VM where i should be able to "query the database"

What i take from that is that i'm not webscraping, and i'm actually going to query the darabase. My script should involve some sort of API where i will (for now) hard code my VM login details to somehow secure a connection to the VM, whereby i will then have access to the database? I don't really know wjat he means by webservice

Can someone help confirm if i'm on the right lines? Maybe help elaborate a bit more? E.g am i connecting to the VM like how i am connecting to the UI (enter IP in browser)? Or am i looking into something that mimicks the remote desktop tool? I really dont have a much of an idea to go on. I assume the former given the "web" in web service

Comment: My new "oh wait" idea after posting this is this webservice is simply to help connect to the UI. I was never meant to actually query the database where this webservice is just a workaround for webscraping a silverlight application, right?

Answer (score 0):

How you wrote what your boss said it is indeed some kind of remote connection. You can specify an URL, database name, password and username in Java to establish a connection to the database. This is not done through the remote desktop tool or via the UI, it does connect on that IP address, however it tries to connect on a different port (location) in the network. Webbrowsers try to access the IP address where for example a MySQL database is accessed through port 3306.

In short:
Java establishes a connection with the database over the internet based on the IP. So it indeed is not webscraping, you get the data directly from the database with database queries.

I hope this answers your question, if not please let me know in the comments and I'll try to ellaborate my answer.